# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the router of my Angular application. I am serving an application and have  deployed it in production on an Apache server. I am serving it from an URL **[www.domain.com/clientng](http://www.domain.com/clientng)** and it works correctly, but the browser console shows this error when for example I try to access **[www.domain.com/clientng/home](http://www.domain.com/clientng/home)**.

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'clientng' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'clientng'`

My router configuration is:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'autologin', component: AutoLoginComponent },
    { path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent },
    { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
];
```

When I compile the application I do it with `--base-href "/ clientng /"` so the index has correctly marked the origin of the documents.

The Apache DocumentRoot is at `/home/user/appweb`, and the angular app is deployed at `/home/user/appweb/clientng`

I do not understand what is happening, because the pages are displayed correctly, and the application works well, but the console shows that error.

Comment: its not your app-routing module.. is it clienting Module right? show me your app-routing module

Answer (score 0):

app- routing module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: LayoutsComponent,
        children: [

            // { path: 'clienting', loadChildren: './components/clienting/clienting.module#ClientingModule'} , 
            

            { path: 'clienting', loadChildren: () => import('./components/clienting/clienting.module').then(m => m.ClientingModule)  },

....
```

then in your clienting Module

use your code

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'autologin', component: AutoLoginComponent },
    { path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent },
    { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routing implementation needs to define full match route :

```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
     {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "/home",
    pathMatch: 'full'
      },

        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'autologin', component: AutoLoginComponent },
        { path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent },
        { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
    ];
```